Exclude specific sheets from script
I have a Google Script that uses getActiveSpreadsheet().  I want to exclude 2 of the sheets.  How can I do this?


function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var excludes = ['ALL','Offices'];
  sheet.getRange("H5:H").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("J5:J").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
}




If you meant the event handler to ignore the event in case the active sheet name belonged to the blacklist, you just need to return from the function if the condition is met:
//exits the function if the active sheet name belongs to the blacklist
if (excludes.includes(sheet.getName())) {
    return;
}

Gets the name of the document
Array.prototype.includes()
And for completeness, this is the whole story:
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var excludes = ['ALL','Offices'];
  
  //exits the function if the active sheet name belongs to the blacklist
  if (excludes.includes(sheet.getName())) {
    return;
  }
  
  sheet.getRange("H5:H").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
  sheet.getRange("J5:J").setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm');
}

